# LSP4J : Language Server method call never ends

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext, language-server-protocol

I have created a Java-based LSP client, but none of the method calls are completed & it waits indefinitely.

```java
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 6008);
Launcher<LanguageServer> createClientLauncher = LSPLauncher.createClientLauncher (languageClient,
                socket.getInputStream(), socket.getOutputStream());
LanguageServer server = createClientLauncher.getRemoteProxy();

createClientLauncher.startListening();
InitializeResult result = server.initialize(new InitializeParams()).get();

System.out.println("end");
```

initialize method never returns. The Language Server is working fine when tested with the VSCode instance.

Seems like requests are not reaching the server as nothing is printed in trace logs of server.

Comment: Are you sure there's a server that's connected to the socket that you provided?